# Verbs After Objects

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

For examples, "I have heard him say/s 'potato.'" "Have you heard me say/s 'carrots care'?" Should I treat them as subjects or should I use their base forms?

Comment: They are infinitives, so "say" is correct.

Answer (score 3):

"say potato" is a complement of the cetenative verb "to hear". And "to hear" as a verb of perception licenses a bare infinitival complement. So it's fine to say,

> Have you heard him **say** potato?

Comment: +1 Yes, "hear" is a catenative verb, and "say potato" is catenative complement. the intervening NP "him" is syntactic object of the matrix clause and the understood subject of the subordinate clause.

Comment: @BillJ I learned it from you :)